# # Computing multiple 1d curves into their 2d array (image) representation

Tags: python, numpy, performance, indexing

I wonder if anyone could please help me do this operation in python as efficiently as possible. I think numpy fancy indexing is the best approach but I have not been able to make it work (any alternative approach is also welcome)

I have simple data sets which take the shape of curves like this:

[image]

I want to compute their image represetation: a matrix where values under the curve are 1 and above 0:

[image]

My current approach consists in using np.searchsorted to map the 1d array values to the number of "pixels" in the image:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# 1D data
n_data = 8
x_data = np.arange(n_data)
y_data = np.array([0.2, 2.3, 5.9, 7.2, 6.2, 4.7, 2.9, 0.9])

# 2D empty data array
y_matrix = np.zeros((n_data, n_data))
rows = np.arange(n_data)[:, np.newaxis]

# Approximation to a 0 to 7 interval
threshold_array = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0])
approximation = np.searchsorted(threshold_array, y_data)
```

Afterwards a simple substraction can generate the 2D mask:

```
# Use broadcasting to create a boolean mask for the elements to be set to 1
mask = n_data - 1 - rows < approximation
y_matrix[mask] = 1

print(y_matrix)
```

This mask looks like:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

Now I would like to apply this opertation to hundreds of thousands of vectors. For example with:

```
y_data = np.array([[0.2, 2.3, 5.9, 7.2, 6.2, 4.7, 2.9, 0.9],
                  [0.2, 2.3, 5.9, 7.2, 6.2, 4.7, 2.9, 0.9],
                  [0.2, 2.3, 5.9, 7.2, 6.2, 4.7, 2.9, 0.9]])
```

Should result into three matrices or an array with (8,8,3) shape. Would anyone offer an efficient approach?

Thanks

Comment: Are the threshold values in `threshold_array` equally spaced? For example, might this need to handle the thresholds `np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.5, 4.0])` ? Or may solutions assume that theshold values are equally far apart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use [numba](/questions/tagged/numba) (and speedup is quite large for large number of vectors):

```py
from numba import njit

@njit
def compute_repr_numba(y_data):
    x, y = y_data.shape

    out = np.zeros(shape=(x, y, y), dtype=np.uint8)

    for i in range(len(y_data)):
        vec = y_data[i]
        out_arr = out[i]
        for j, val in enumerate(vec):
            for k in range(y - 1, y - int(np.ceil(val)) - 1, -1):
                out_arr[k, j] = 1

    return out

y_data = np.array(
    [
        [0.2, 2.3, 5.9, 7.2, 6.2, 4.7, 2.9, 0.9],
        [0.0, 0.0, 5.9, 7.2, 6.2, 4.7, 2.9, 0.9],
    ]
)
print(compute_repr_numba_single(y_data))
```

Prints:

```py
[[[0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
  [0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0]
  [0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0]
  [0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0]
  [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]
  [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]
  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]

 [[0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
  [0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0]
  [0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0]
  [0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0]
  [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0]
  [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0]
  [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1]]]
```

---

Benchmark (+ using parallelization):

```py
import perfplot
from numba import njit, prange


def compute_repr_normal(y_data):
    x, y = y_data.shape
    threshold_array = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0])

    out = np.zeros(shape=(x, y, y), dtype=np.uint8)

    for i, vec in enumerate(y_data):
        rows = np.arange(y)[:, np.newaxis]
        approximation = np.searchsorted(threshold_array, vec)
        mask = y - 1 - rows < approximation
        out[i, mask] = 1

    return out


@njit
def compute_repr_numba_single(y_data):
    x, y = y_data.shape

    out = np.zeros(shape=(x, y, y), dtype=np.uint8)

    for i in range(len(y_data)):
        vec = y_data[i]
        out_arr = out[i]
        for j, val in enumerate(vec):
            for k in range(y - 1, y - int(np.ceil(val)) - 1, -1):
                out_arr[k, j] = 1

    return out


@njit(parallel=True)
def compute_repr_numba_parallel(y_data):
    x, y = y_data.shape

    out = np.zeros(shape=(x, y, y), dtype=np.uint8)

    for i in prange(len(y_data)):
        vec = y_data[i]
        out_arr = out[i]
        for j, val in enumerate(vec):
            for k in range(y - 1, y - int(np.ceil(val)) - 1, -1):
                out_arr[k, j] = 1

    return out


def compute_repr_oskar(y_data):
    x, y = y_data.shape
    x_data = np.arange(y)

    images = np.tile(y_data[:, None, :], (1, y, 1))
    images = images > x_data[::-1, None]
    images = images.astype(np.uint8)
    return images


y_data = np.array(
    [
        [0.0, 0.0, 5.9, 7.2, 6.2, 4.7, 2.9, 0.9],
    ]
)

assert np.allclose(compute_repr_numba_parallel(y_data), compute_repr_normal(y_data))
assert np.allclose(compute_repr_numba_single(y_data), compute_repr_normal(y_data))
assert np.allclose(compute_repr_oskar(y_data), compute_repr_normal(y_data))

np.random.seed(0)

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: np.random.random(size=(n, 8)),
    kernels=[
        compute_repr_normal,
        compute_repr_numba_parallel,
        compute_repr_numba_single,
        compute_repr_oskar,
    ],
    labels=["normal", "numba_parallel", "numba_single", "compute_repr_oskar"],
    n_range=[5, 10, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 10_000, 50_000, 250_000],
    xlabel="N",
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    equality_check=np.allclose,
)
```

On my machine (AMD 5700x) produces this graph:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Andrej Kesely. I am not familiar with numba but this is a great learning example.

Answer (score 2):

Pure numpy implementation:

```py
import numpy as np

# data
n_data = 8
x_data = np.arange(n_data)
# I varied the 2nd and 3rd list to better visualize the functionality
y_data = np.array([[0.2, 2.3, 5.9, 7.2, 6.2, 4.7, 2.9, 0.9],
                  [1.2, 1.3, 4.9, 7.2, 4.2, 4.7, 2.9, 0.9],
                  [2.2, 2.3, 7.9, 6.2, 5.2, 3.7, 1.9, 0.9]])

images = np.tile(y_data[:,None,:], (1,n_data,1))
images = images > x_data[::-1,None]
images = images.astype(float)

print(images)
```

Output:

```
[[[0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
  [0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]

 [[0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]]
```

Comment: Thank you @Oskar Hofmann, I wished I could accept both answers... but I will be using this one for my library in case the user has not installed numba.

Comment: @OskarHofmann I did a benchmark and this solution is faster than original but ~one magnitude slower than numba. Also when `y_data` has `0` value I think it computes `1` instead of `0`.

Comment: Yeah I just benchmarked as well and numba is indeed faster. But I checked and a 0 in `y_data` does correctly lead to a 0.

Comment: @OskarHofmann Yes, you're right - I used the older version, with `<`